# How to pass item in array item to powershell command that uses a filter

Tags: azure, powershell

```
accounts=$(az ad sp list --show-mine --query [].appDisplayName -otsv)
```

This will give me an array

I want to pass each item to an array in this command

```
foreach ($myApp in $accounts){
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq $myApp"
}
```

When I try this I get syntax error at position
is this even possible

I'm a noob to powershell

Comment: You need to quote the right-hand side operand in the filter expression: `Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$myApp'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried enclosing your variable in single quotes?

According to the documentation the value in the filter is quoted:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1-get-an-application-by-display-name

```
foreach ($myApp in $accounts){
    Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$myApp'"
}
```

Comment: This was it.  I wsa missing that.  I was able to take this make a new array and then pass that to another function.  I Kept banging my head.  Thanks!!!